# Python Pulling values from OrderedDict

Tags: python

How would I pull 'FirstName' out of this OrderedDict in Python?

```
OrderedDict([(u'totalSize', 1),
             (u'done', True),
             (u'records',
             [OrderedDict([
             (u'attributes',
             OrderedDict([
             (u'type', u'Contact'),
(u'url',u'/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/003290000089vSgAAI')])), 
(u'FirstName', u'John'), (u'LastName', u'Smith')])])])
```

Comment: `my_dict['records'][0]['FirstName']`?

Comment: Why does this structure exist in the first place? Do you create it?

Comment: This is a response from a Salesforce API call. With the code recommended I receive error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @user2998288 That code has been proven to work by [Haifeng Zhang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46247573/1222951). If it doesn't work for you, then your data structure is different than the one you posted in the question. Since we have no way to tell what your data really looks like, and you haven't bothered posting the correct data, I'm voting to close this as off topic as it lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = OrderedDict([('totalSize', 1), ('done', True), ('records', [OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Contact'), ('url', '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/003290000089vSgAAI')])), ('FirstName', 'John'), ('LastName', 'Smith')])])])
>>> a['records'][0]['FirstName']
'John'
```

The inner OrderedDict object is inside a list(this list only contains the OrderedDict object)

Comment: This is a response from a Salesforce API call. With the code recommended I receive error "IndexError: list index out of range"